# std::exception's what() returns "std::exception"

Tags: c++, exception, stl

Java person here stuck doing some c++.  I'm catching an exception and trying to diagnose where it is coming from (regrettably the exception is not thrown when run via gdb).  However, when I print out the what() of the exception I simply get the string "std::exception".  Is this specific to anything in the standard library or do lots of standard exceptions return this?  Here is what I am doing to print:

```
    } catch (const std::exception & ex) {
      std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
```

The output is just:

```
std::exception
```

Also, I'm working in a fairly large code-base, it is possible that this is coming from some exception on our end but I have yet to find it through regular search techniques so I'm currently leaning towards this coming from the standard libraries.

I'm using g++ 4.8 if that is relevant.

Comment: Do you get a core dump you can load up in gdb and do a backtrace on?

Comment: Where is the exception thrown? How is it thrown? What exception is thrown? Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: That seems unusual for a GCC library exception - I'd expect a more specific derived class like `std::runtime_error`, `std::length_error` etc. (one of [these](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception)) with `.what()` communicating that.   I think this is probably from within your own code base.  Might not help, but if I were you'd I'd try a recursive grep for `'throw\s+std::exception'` in your own code, and if that doesn't turn up anything you could try the GCC headers.

Comment: Is that the default string for a std::exception then?  That could be possible.  I was grepping for the string "std::exception" but if that would be the default string then that string itself might not be in the code base.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, no core dump.  I can't load it into gdb because it's a pretty rare occurrence (happens about one out of every 50k times I run my test) and it disappears completely when run in gdb (heisenbug).  Unfortunately, I don't have a MCVE, as that would have solved the problem.  I was looking more for a reference to STL exception strings or someone else who'd run into a similar exception before I started putting a try/catch around every single STL call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ exceptions are completely different from Java exceptions.

The C++ standard specifies that the string returned by what() is completely arbitrary, and implementation-defined:

```
virtual const char* what() const noexcept;

Returns: An implementation-defined ntbs.
Remarks: The message may be a null-terminated multibyte string
(17.5.2.1.4.2), suitable for conversion
and display as a wstring (21.3, 22.4.1.4). The return value remains 
valid until the exception object
from which it is obtained is destroyed or a non-const member
function of the exception object is called.
```

The return value you're getting, "std::exception" is perfectly compliant with the C++ standard.

Don't rely on C++ exceptions to tell you exactly where they were thrown from after you catch them, like Java does. This is outside of the scope of the C++ standard. In C++, an exception is really nothing more than a mechanism for transferring execution control flow.

Having said that: many C++ implementation will provide you with some implementation-specific mechanisms for dumping the current stack backtrace, to the best of the runtime library's abilities. Check your C++ compiler's documentation for more information.

gcc, for example, offers backtrace(), together with some gcc internal functions to convert the raw addresses returned by backtrace() into symbols, and other functions for demangling the symbols. Using that, a rough analogue to Java's exception handling can be concocted; although gcc's implementation isn't perfect, and has some functional holes, and that also requires advance planning, and custom exception classes whose constructors capture the current stack frame (*before* the exception gets actually thrown); and, once caught, the thrown exception class instance can be inspected for the captured backtrace information.

But that doesn't really help your current situation. I would suggest that you check your C++ compiler's documentation, as I suggested, and also investigate your debugger's capabilities. A C++ debugger should allow you to set a breakpoint when any exceptions get thrown, and before it is caught, so that you can examine the stack backtrace via the debugger, when the exception occurs.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look into backtrace.  That might save me from doing a binary search through the entire code base!

Comment: backtrace helped (never could get the symbols to resolve correctly but I was able to save them off and then later feed them into gdb to get the locations) and I was able to eventually stumble my way into the root of the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: This answer makes it sound as if exception messages are generally implementation-defined in C++, but this applies only to the `std::exception` base class and not to derived classes like `std::runtime_error`, where `what` is guaranteed to return the string you passed in the constructor. For example, §22.2.7/3 says: *"Postconditions: `strcmp(what(), what_arg.c_str()) == 0`*". IOW, if I create a `std::runtime_error x("foo")`, then `what` must not return `"std::exception"`.

Answer (score 34):

This could be because of two things:

1. Someone just does `throw std::exception()` somewhere, which is not very helpful.
2. A class derived from `std::exception` gets copied to `std::exception`. This is a problem called [Object Slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

I just made the second mistake myself actually. I had this code:

```
try
{
    // Some Boost stuff
}
catch (std::exception e)
{
    cerr << e.what() << endl;
}
```

You must make sure to do `std::exception& e`. I know you didn't make this mistake but it's possible someone else did further within the code (or someone coming here from Google).

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the &.